# Elementary differential equations: $xy' + x\sin x = y^3\cos^2 x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving the DE $$xy' + x\sin x = y^3\cos^2 x$$ I am confused on which procedure to use, would be grateful if you help me

Comment: Can you double check that you typed the equation correctly?

Comment: $y' =- \sin x + \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}y^3\quad$ is an Abel's ODE. Generally very difficult to solve analytically. Better use a numerical method of solving.

Comment: More specifically, it is an [Abel equation of the *first kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Ok, so how is it resolved, please can you help me out?

Comment: @user254433, yes the question was typed correcctly

Answer (score 0):

What the comments said.  Unless there is some coincidence, this cannot be solved in closed form.  I'm with the commenter who conjectures the problem was mistyped.  But the OP reiterates that it is correct...

So you must solve it numerically.  Or by series.  Or using an existence-uniqueness theorem: it is first-order after all.

There seems to be a particular series solution like this:
$$
y_p = -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{45}+\dots
$$

Comment: I got $y\approx -\frac{7277 x^{10}}{1814400}+\frac{947 x^8}{80640}-\frac{x^6}{45}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}$